Choose a good estimator in a candidate set
Recently, I've been interested in the following statistical problem:
I have a set that consists of some estimators $\hat{A}_i$ of a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$. Then I have some data available for testing, and I want to use the test set to select the best performing $\hat{A}_i$. Is there a theoretical guarantee for this approach?
Suppose I know the convergence rate of each estimator $\hat{A}_i$ in the candidate set. Can I obtain the convergence rate of the final estimator selected by the data-driven method?
Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE
The model
$$
Y=AX+E
$$
where $E$ is a Gaussian noise matrix.
Consider a matrix-response regression
$$
\hat{A}=\frac{1}{2}\arg\min\|Y-AX\|_F^2+\text{penalty}.
$$
Different kinds of penalty are used to get the estimator $\hat{A}_i$. Anyway, I can get some 'weak estimators' through some methods, not just regression, but even neural networks.
Then I have a test set $\{Y_{\text{test}}, X_{\text{test}}\}$ and want to choose a good one in $\hat{A}_i$ using the test set. By calculating
$$
\|Y_{\text{test}}-\hat{A}_i X_{\text{test}}\|_F^2,
$$
I want to choose the one with the smallest obtained value as the final result.
In this framework, could I get some statistical guarantees?

What does it mean to estimate a matrix? Also, what does it have to do with machine learning or cross validation? (This second question might have an obvious answer once you clarify the first question.)

@Dave I update my question

Write $I$ for the chosen index.  An apparently trivial bound is that the error for $A_I$ is no more than the sum of the errors for all the $A_i$. If the number of candidate estimators $p$ is small, or is fixed as $n\to\infty$ or something, then this may be enough.
Other useful bounds along these lines require moments. If $E[\text{error}(A_i)^M]$ exists then
$$E[\text{error}(A_I)^M]^{1/M}\leq K p^{1/M}\max_i E[\text{error}(A_i)^M]^{1/M}$$
for a constant $K$ depending only on $M$. Finite-maximum bounds like this are the basis of chaining arguments in empirical processes.
